# nginx erratic error "111: Connection refused while serving video file"

Tags: nginx, video

I have this server, a debian 10 arm64 machine on which I host an asp core 3.1 video streaming website.

Overall it is working just fine except that sometimes when playing a video, for some reason nginx is generating a lot of:

```
*258 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```

when serving some video files.

Now this is especially weird because:

- I get this error logged despite the video being loaded and played successfully
- From time to time, my system seem to crash - presumably due to this behaviour (because this crash does not occur when nginx service is stopped) - and ends up being full read only. I then have to restart it to recover.

Here's my configuration:

```
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name videocloud.my-domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/videocloud.my-domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/videocloud.my-domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file      /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;

    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Accept-Ranges;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin [http://localhost:5002];
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Accept-Ranges;
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Encoding;
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Range;
    add_header accept_ranges bytes;

    proxy_force_ranges on;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:5002;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:5002 https://videocloud.my-domain.com;
    }

}
```

Comment: Any change if your replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` or disable ipv6? Related: [serverfault.com/a/576488/505837](https://serverfault.com/a/576488/505837).
And you can change your [proxy_redirect](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) to `proxy_redirect default;`.

Comment: wow thanks ! this actually did the trick !

Comment: Marc, please write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments above, the issue was solved by replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 and disabling ipv6